# Xarray to_netcdf very slow and crashes for large dataset in python

Tags: python, dask, netcdf4, python-xarray

I am trying to resample precipitation data, PET-data and temperature data from hourly to six hourly with xarray in Python. After this step, the idea is to merge these three datasets into one netCDF4-file. Until this merge, xarray performs reasonably fast (approximately 40 seconds), but the save to netcdf takes two days and then crashes. 
The data is together ~25GB.

I saw that this problem occurs more often, but I have not found any solution yet..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Below my used code:

```
import xarray 
import datetime 
from datetime import * 
import time


start = time.time()`


# Rhine 
P = xarray.open_dataset("D:\P_Rhine_total.nc", decode_times=True, chunks={'time':500}) 
P = P.sel(time=slice(datetime(2010, 1, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 12, 31, 0))) 
Pnew = P.precipitation_thickness.rename("P") 
Pagg = Pnew.resample('6H','time',how='sum', closed='right', label='right')  
PET = xarray.open_dataset("D:\PET_Rhine_total.nc", decode_times=True, chunks={'time':500}) 
PET = PET.sel(time=slice(datetime(2010, 1, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 12, 31, 0))) 
PETnew = PET.makkink_potential_evaporation.rename("PET") 
PETagg = PETnew.resample('6H','time',how='sum', closed='right', label='right') 

T = xarray.open_dataset("D: \T_Rhine_total.nc", decode_times=True, chunks={'time':500}) 
T = T.sel(time=slice(datetime(2010, 1, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 12, 31, 0))) 
Tnew = T.air_temperature.rename("TEMP") 
Tagg = Tnew.resample('6H','time',how='mean', closed='right', label='right') 

New = xarray.merge((Pagg,PETagg,Tagg)) 
New.chunk(chunks={'time':500}) 
New.to_netcdf(path="D:\\forcing_Rhine.nc",mode="w",format="NETCDF4", encoding={'P': {'dtype': 'float32', 'scale_factor': 0.001, '_FillValue': -9999}, 'PET': {'dtype': 'float32', 'scale_factor': 0.001, '_FillValue': -9999}, 'TEMP': {'dtype': 'float32', 'scale_factor': 0.001, '_FillValue': -9999}}) 
End = time.time() 
print End-start
```

Comment: Can you provide information about the shapes of your input arrays? That can make a big difference in computational efficiency with dask -- you may very well need more or different chunking.

Comment: I am sorry for my late reaction, I have fixed the problem in the meantime! I have changed the chunking a bit, but I found out that after the resampling method the chunking was lost (there was still one, but chunked on every timestep). So, the new step is to assign new chunks after the resampling. Thanks again for your response though!

Comment: I'd love to see a more general form of this question and answer.  What's the *general* approach to writing large Xarray datasets?  If we have a dataset that causes an out of memory error or runs forever trying to save to disk, what should we do to troubleshoot? Is chunking the right thing? If so, how should we think about choosing a chunking strategy? etc.